# hyperlink with background image: only scale down image if it's too large, otherwise use original

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, image-scaling, graphical-logo

**background**

- Bootstrap
- Fixed top navbar with brand logo for each client (logo configurable by client, size varies)
- logo is background image for a brand hyperlink

**Expected behavior**

- if logo is smaller than 60px, then show original logo;
- if logo is larger than 60px, then scale it down to 60px wide

**Have Tried**

```
#logo {
  background-position: left center !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  max-width: 60px;
}
```

**Problems**

- hyperlink is not scaleable for some reason when apply different logo image backgrounds
- if I add a width rule to #logo (width: 60px) to give it a static width, then large image will be cut off at 60px, not scaling down; then if apply small logos, there will be unused space on the right due to 60px static width

**Fiddle link**

click [here](http://www.bootply.com/xL2TiGDK6y) to bootply